# Model field for implicit many-to-many (many-to-many-to-many) relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

Let us say in my models for a django app, I have three models, each with many to many relationship (this is a toy example).

```
class User(models.Model):

    permissions_group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class Group(models.Model):

    permissions_area = models.ManyToManyField(Area)

class Area(models.Model):
    #other irrelevant field data...
    pass
```

I would like to have a field on my `User` model, that expressed the relationship between users and Areas, which is an implicit many-to-many model (that is to say I don't define additional relations which create additional tables in the database, I use the relationship which goes through groups).

I have considered using a custom manager, but that doesn't seem to allow the kind of relationship filtering that one sees with a standard RelatedField manager; I could simply set a decorated property on the class:

```
class User(models.Model):

    @property
    permissions_areas(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(group__in=self.permissions_groups.all())
```

But that seems clunky, and doesn't use any django conventions. Is there a conventional way to do this in django using Django's tooling (custom managers or something similar to `RelatedManager`) which I am missing?

Comment: Your solution is absolutely OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use two underscores to look through a relation, so:

```
class User(models.Model):

    @property
    permissions_areas(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(group__user=self).distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` is useful if a `User` can belong to *multiple* groups that have access to this area. Without `.distinct()` it would return that `Area` for each group that has permission to that area and where the user belongs to.

Comment: That's definitely neater than my construction, but using the `@property` decorator isn't exactly the route I want to take if I can avoid it (would much prefer something like the `RelatedManager` class

Comment: Note that in this answer (and in your example), `user.permissions_areas` gives you a queryset, so you can filter(), delete(), update(), etc. For example `user.permissions_areas.filter(some_field__contains='x')`. It's not a RelatedManager interface, but still pretty versatile.